# Force a code to execute once in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a particular scenario. I have an immediate function which executed on each page on load.

```
 (function () {
      if (readcookie(login)) { //i need to make it execute only once
           document.head.appendChild(iframe);
      } else {
         //nothing  
      }  
  }());
```

Is it possible to execute this if statement only once, i cant modify the login cookie. Also i dont want to use a global variable or a new cookie.

Comment: Could you phrase your question a bit better? Currently it is quite hard to figure out what you're trying to do and what it is that your issue is

Comment: re-phrased the question.

Comment: It's still unclear what you are asking. It will only execute once, at least until you rerun the entire program by loading a new page.

Comment: *"Also i dont want to use a global variable or a new cookie"*: that's almost like saying: I need to remember something, but don't want to use memory.

Comment: This smells like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/) anyway. What does the code do? Why do you want it to run "only once"? Why have you ruled out cookies and globals as solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [**`sessionStorage`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) to remember if your code has been executed in previous page loads:

```
(function () {
    // Check that your custom storage variable is not set.
    if (!sessionStorage.frameAppended) {
        // If this is the first time the code is executed,
        // create a boolean variable in the storage.
        sessionStorage.frameAppended = true;

        // Add the code that needs to be executed only once below this point.
        if (readcookie(login)) {
            document.head.appendChild(iframe);
        }
    }
}());
```

If you want your custom data to be stored forever (as opposed to per browser session), you can use [**`localStorage`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) instead.

Comment: Note that even `localStorage` will be cleared when you clear the browser data, and the code would run again.

Comment: @Xotic750 that is true, but there is no way around that, not with any other approach.

Comment: yes, thats true. And session cookie will work. I want it to delete when browser session expired. I did this way :- `if (readcookie(login) && !readCookie(frameAppended)) {
            document.head.appendChild(iframe); create session cookie 'frame appended';
        }`